# How to detect every storage USB device connected to mac os x?

Tags: macos, cocoa, usb

I'm working on a cocoa app that detects any USB storage device (flash disk, Smartphone...) connected to the Mac and then use its files. In all the tutorials I've yet read, I have to specify the vendor id and the product id however, I want my app to detect ANY storage USB device. I'm working on Mac os x.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use IOKit to inspect all services matching `kIOUSBDeviceClassName`, and then call `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties()` on each, and inspect the value of kUSBDeviceClass, going by the Device Class Codes described at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/USBSpec_header_reference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Device_Class_Codes